# Update item in Mongoid Database in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have created a database using Mongoid and using Ruby.

The database creation works fine, I need to update the field 'status' of my database but I can't do it using the update ap.

I have wrote :

```
def update_database (id, status)
  @@logger.info("Reservation Id: #{id}")
  @@logger.info("Status: #{status}")
  item = ReservationDb.find( id: id )
  @@logger.info("DB entry: #{item}")
  item[:status] = status
  ReservationDb.update({"_id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(id)}, item)
end
```

The last line of ReservationDb.update is not acception as it is. All example found are passing 2 arguments but ruby complain and seems only allowing 0 or 1 args.

What I am trying to do is to update the field status associated to a specific mongoId.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is `ReservationDb`? If you're using Mongoid, wouldn't you be doing things like `some_document.update(:status => status)`?

Comment: The issue was coming from the way I am using update. the update must be made on the item found and not the database